# How to retrieve url in spring boot and use it in Angular?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

In spring boot, the base url maybe `localhost:8080` or a different one. Now I want to use it in angular. I saw that many examples online just hardcode it in angular http client call code.

But the base url can be changed, for example the port number changed or the environment is changed from dev to qa or production. So my question is that possible dynamically expose it from spring boot and retrieve it from angular?

Comment: you can use environment files in angular to set different url. Then you can build the project using one of these environments files so it matchs aq/dev/prod url. You can't dynamically expose it from spring boot in your situation because in order to retrieve it from Angular, you need to know the actual url...that you don't yet know

Answer (score 1):

Your app should contain files at src/environments called environment.ts and environment.prod.ts. You can include a constant key value pair for your apiURL in this file like so:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'localhost:8080'
}
```

And also include your production URL in the prod file. You can then use it in a file like so:

```
import { environment } from 'src/environment/environment.ts';
...
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  url: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.url = environment.apiUrl;
  }
}
```